# How can I use regexextract function in Google Sheets to get text and numbers contained in quotation marks

Tags: regex, google-sheets

My string is in G14

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"Store Name";s:12:"FIRST CHOICE";s:12:"Amount Spent";s:2:"50";}i:1;a:2:{s:10:"Store Name";s:13:"SECOND CHOICE";s:12:"Amount Spent";s:3:"100";}}
```

I need to extract both the store names and amount spent values. 
i.e. "FIRST CHOICE" "50" "SECOND CHOICE" "100"
Currently, I can extract the text by using

```
=trim(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(G14,"\b\w[^A-Z]*\b"," "),"\W+"," "))
```

But nothing I try will extract the numbers as well.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! My only issue now is if the numerical value has a decimal then it gets excluded. Is there a solution for this? Also I assume if the value includes a "$" this will cause problems? Apologies I should have allowed for this in my original post.

Comment: Just to confirm, both your solutions work, so I am using pattern 1.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, just hoping for a solution for including dollar signs and decimal places, but yes Thilina's initial solution was very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you about ``Thilina's initial solution``? If you have other solution from other user, can you provide it? I would like to study from it. If my solution was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize you.

Comment: @Thilina Nakkawita OP said ``Thilina's initial solution was very helpful.``. If you had posted the answer, can you provide it? I would like to study from it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this answer as one of them.

In these patterns, it supposes that `a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"Store Name";s:12:"FIRST CHOICE";s:12:"Amount Spent";s:2:"50";}i:1;a:2:{s:10:"Store Name";s:13:"SECOND CHOICE";s:12:"Amount Spent";s:3:"100";}}` is put in "G14".

### Pattern 1:

```
=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(G14,REGEXREPLACE(G14,"(""[A-Z0-9 ]+"")","($1)")),"""",""))))
```

1. Using `REGEXREPLACE()`, it encloses `"FIRST CHOICE"`, `"50"`, `"SECOND CHOICE"` and `"100"` by `()`.
2. Using `REGEXEXTRACT()`, it retrieves `"FIRST CHOICE"`, `"50"`, `"SECOND CHOICE"` and `"100"` from the original value.
3. Remove `"`.
4. Join.

### Pattern 2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(G14,";"),"""[A-Z 0-9]+"""))))),"""","")
```

1. Using `SPLIT()`, it splits the original value by `;`.
2. Using `REGEXEXTRACT()`, it retrieves `"FIRST CHOICE"`, `"50"`, `"SECOND CHOICE"` and `"100"`. At that time, it removes `#N/A` using `IFERROR()`.
3. Using `TEXTJOIN()`, it joins the array retrieved by `REGEXEXTRACT()`.
4. Remove `"`.

### Result:

Both results are the same.

[image]

### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.